# Can click once installed applications like the Template Builder and Content Porter be installed using Chrome?

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013, template-builder

It works OK in Internet explorer, but with Chrome/Firefox I get errors opening the .application file which is downloaded - typically something along the lines of

> ...application is missing required files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chrome has an extension to launch ClickOnce applications. It includes a mime type mapper that will correctly launch x-ms-applications when a link to a `.application` is clicked.

You can find it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickonce-for-google-chro/eeifaoomkminpbeebjdmdojbhmagnncl?hl=en

Adding that will allow you to open the Template Builder from Chrome just as you would in IE, not sure if something similar exists from Firefox.

Comment: You'll want to disable the extension immediately after installing TemplateBuilder.  It injects Ads into your pages.

Comment: @robrtc I don't think I ever saw an ad in my pages, but there is an option to disable the ads in the extension options too.

Answer (score 4):

It's not supported by default, but you can try this add-in: **https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickonce-for-google-chro/eeifaoomkminpbeebjdmdojbhmagnncl**

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Bart & user978511 has suggested to use for Chrome; for FireFox as well there is a similar Add-on - FxClickonce 0.1. This is available at below URL from where you can add it to your FireFox Browser:

[**FxClickonce**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fxclickonce/)

Or you may want to search for it in your Browser Add-on Page.

In addition to using ClickOnce add on for Chrome & FireFox OR using Internet Explorer by default to download the Content Porter or Template Builder, you can additionally do the following as well:

- **Content Porter:** Copy the `cp.application` file from your Tridion Installation from following path: `/TridionRoot/Content Porter/ImportExportService/Client/cp.application` and install using it
- **Template Builder:** Copy the `TcmTemplateBuilder.application` from your Tridion Installation from the following path: `/TridionWeb/TemplateBuilder/TcmTemplateBuilder.application` and install using it